# Exception about same tracked Id even when state is Detached

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Before attach an entity I check its state:

```
if (_context.Entry(item).State == EntityState.Detached) 
    _context.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
```

but it raises anyway the following exception:

> Attaching an entity of type 'Order' failed because another entity of the same type already has the same primary key value. This can happen when using the 'Attach' method or setting the state of an entity to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' if any entities in the graph have conflicting key values. This may be because some entities are new and have not yet received database-generated key values. In this case use the 'Add' method or the 'Added' entity state to track the graph and then set the state of non-new entities to 'Unchanged' or 'Modified' as appropriate.

I don't fully understand the message.
The item is existing and I retrieved it using a AsNoTracking() query:

```
public Order GetOrder(int year, int number)
{
    try
    {
        _context.Orders.AsNoTracking().Single(x => x.Year == year && x.Number == number);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

so, if it's not tracked (and the detached state confirm it) why I cannot attach it to update a value?

Comment: Another *instance* of the same order is already attached.

Comment: @GertArnold ALL my queries (single, where, count, etc...) run with AsNoTracking(), How might I (inadvertently) attached another instance?

Comment: Don't ask me :) But that's the only conclusion I can draw from the exception. Maybe you attached an object having an `Order` in it.

Comment: @GertArnold well, this a useful information - thanks

Comment: In code that fails you are attaching order to context for example. So if you run this code 2 times for the same context and different order instances (with same PK) - second one will fail.

Comment: Sadly EF doesn't provide a good method for checking if another instance with the same key is tracked (even EFC). But you can find tracked instances in `_context.Orders.Local` collection.